# Simple Image-Similarity-Search function (Need a Script or Plugin for my study web-project)

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, html, similarity

I'm searching for a simple script for my web-project. 
For example: There is a simple website where you can upload an image, and If you click on the "find similar Images"-Button, it shows you similar images (similar colored picture) (from a file with many other images).

Is there a free and simple script where I can use it for my web-project (HTML5/JavaScript)?

I found this one, but I am not sure If it is good enough to use it: http://tcorral.github.com/IM.js/

Good Advices are welcome :)